# Convert list of conditional expressions to list

Tags: replacement, conditional

I have a long list of items of the form

```
{{t -> ConditionalExpression[1/3 ((149 Pi)/130 + m Pi) if n == 1 && m == -1], 
  u -> ConditionalExpression[(149 Pi)/390 if n == 1 && m == -1]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[1/3 ((179 Pi)/130 + m Pi) if m == -1 && n == 2], 
  u -> ConditionalExpression[(179 Pi)/390 if m == -1 && n == 2]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[1/3 ((209 Pi)/130 + m Pi) if m == -1 && n == 3], 
  u -> ConditionalExpression[(209 Pi)/390 if m == -1 && n == 3]}
}
```

and would like to convert them by making the substitutions for $m$ and $n$ and producing (in this case) the list

```
{{t -> 1/3 (19 Pi/130), u -> 49 Pi/390 },
 {t -> 1/3 (49 Pi/130), u -> 179 Pi/390 },
 {t -> 1/3 (79 Pi/130), u -> 209 Pi/390} }
```

or the equivalent.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

The correct syntax for [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) is

```
list = {{t -> 
     ConditionalExpression[1/3 ((149 Pi)/130 + m Pi), n == 1 && m == -1], 
    u -> ConditionalExpression[(149 Pi)/390, n == 1 && m == -1]}, {t -> 
     ConditionalExpression[1/3 ((179 Pi)/130 + m Pi), m == -1 && n == 2], 
    u -> ConditionalExpression[(179 Pi)/390, m == -1 && n == 2]}, {t -> 
     ConditionalExpression[1/3 ((209 Pi)/130 + m Pi), m == -1 && n == 3], 
    u -> ConditionalExpression[(209 Pi)/390, m == -1 && n == 3]}};
```

Use the condition as an assumption with [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html)

```
list2 = list /. ConditionalExpression -> Simplify

(* {{t -> (19 π)/390, u -> (149 π)/390}, {t -> (49 π)/390, 
  u -> (179 π)/390}, {t -> (79 π)/390, u -> (209 π)/390}} *)
```